# Remove node from TreeView

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to create this simple example of javaFX TreeView with context menu which can remove nodes from the tree:

```
public class TreeViewSample extends Application {

    private final Node rootIcon = new ImageView(
        new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("folder_16.png"))
    );

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Tree View Sample");        

        TreeItem<String> rootItem = new TreeItem<String> ("Inbox", rootIcon);
        rootItem.setExpanded(true);
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            TreeItem<String> item = new TreeItem<String> ("Message" + i);            
            rootItem.getChildren().add(item);
        }        
        TreeView<String> tree = new TreeView<String> (rootItem);        
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(tree);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I tested this context menu to remove right click selected node:

```
final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem("About");
        item1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("About");
            }
        });
        MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem("Preferences");
        item2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("Preferences");
            }
        });
        MenuItem item3 = new MenuItem("Remove");
        item3.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e)
            {

                DynamicTreeNodeModel c = treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getValue();
                boolean remove = treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getChildren().remove(c);
                System.out.println("Remove");
            }
        });
        contextMenu.getItems().addAll(item1, item2, item3);

        treeView.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
```

For some reason the code is not working. Can you help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're trying to remove the selected node from it's own children.  Since it doesn't exist there, nothing happens.  You need to remove the selected node from it's parent's children.

```
    MenuItem item3 = new MenuItem("Remove");
    item3.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            TreeItem c = (TreeItem)treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            boolean remove = c.getParent().getChildren().remove(c);
            System.out.println("Remove");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you mean it was working and now it isn't?  I changed it a bit since I don't have a `DynamicTreeNodeModel` class.  I tested it and it works fine.

Comment: You're making TreeItem<String> , the example code is TreeItem<Dynamic etc>.  That's going to cause you problems.  You can still remove a generic TreeItem without declaring it's type.

Comment: I tested your solution and it works. How should I edit the delete handler in order to follow your advice?

Comment: You don't have to change anything.  Your just deleting the TreeItem, not accessing it's value. The problem you'll have is when you use TreeItem.getValue() and expect one type of object and you get some other type.